# CMake project for Emscripten

Tags: c++, cmake, emscripten

I want to make CMake and Emscripten friends. Didn't find more or less informative documentation on the Emscripten project website, but they provide CMake toolchain file so I think it should be possible.
So far very basic compilation without advanced parameters works fine, but I have issues while using `embind` and preloading files.

1. Linking process seems to miss Emscripten "binaries" and produces warnings for all embind related functions like this one: `warning: unresolved symbol: _embind_register_class` which results in respective errors while loading compiled JS file in rowser.
2. No `.data` file is generated during the compilation.

I've created a minimalistic example which includes two targets: one "normal" (client) and one manual (manual-client) which simply runs emcc as I expect it to be run: https://github.com/xwaffelx/minimal-cmake-emscripten-project/blob/master/README.md

Although manual way works, I don't think it is a proper way to do it...

--- Update ---

As requested, here is even more short example:

1. CMakeLists.txt file

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
   cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)
   project(emtest)
   set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
   set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build.emscripten)
   include_directories("lib/assimp/include")
   link_directories("lib/assimp/lib-js")
   link_libraries("assimp")
   file(GLOB_RECURSE CORE_HDR src/.h)
   file(GLOB_RECURSE CORE_SRC src/.cpp)
   add_definitions("-s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1 --preload-file ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets --bind")
   add_executable(client ${CORE_SRC} ${CORE_HDR})
   ```

Result should be equivalent to running the following command manualy:

```
emcc 
    -Ilib/assimp/include 
    -s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1
    --preload-file assets
    --bind
    Application.cpp 
    lib/assimp/lib-js/libassimp.so 
    -o client.js
```

Here is the Application.cpp:

```
#include "Application.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>

void Application::Initialize() {
    std::cout << "Initializing application." << std::endl;
    Assimp::Importer importer; // For test purpose
}

void Application::SayHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

and Application.h:

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_H
#define APPLICATION_H

#include <emscripten/html5.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

namespace e = emscripten;

class Application {
public:
    void Initialize();
    void SayHello();
};

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(EMTest) {
  e::class_<Application>("Application")
    .constructor()
      .function("Initialize", &Application::Initialize)
      .function("SayHello", &Application::SayHello);
}

#endif
```

THen I run cmake as follows:
`cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PATH=path/to/Emscripten.cmake .. && make`
However, warnings like `warning: unresolved symbol: _embind_register_class` are produced during linking and running the code and no preloaded data in `client.data` file is created while compiling CMake project. At the same time no warnings and everything runs OK while compiling manually.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution was to specify all the flags during the linking by providing following CMake instruction:
`set_target_properties(client PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1 --preload-file assets --bind")`

Thanks to developers of emscripten who helped in the github issues tracker.

Comment: Sorry, which file did you modify?
Makefile?

Comment: No, CMakeLists.txt file. Just use `set_target_properties` entry to specify linker arguments.